# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

[image: Error Image]

I am trying to run this code and expected to have 5 li with same text Video. Instead, I am getting this.  Please help me solve it. I have attached all the error screenshot and also the codes.

It works fine If I just trying to print the count of the array which is 5 it works fine. But if I try the below code it's come with the error. It works fine no error in terminal but this comes in a console and not printing the Video 5 time as it should.

search_bar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { term: '' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    value={this.state.term}
                    onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';

const API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { videos: [] };

        YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: 'trump' }, (videos) => {
            this.setState({ videos });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar />
                <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


//Take this component's generated HTML and put it on the page.(in the DOM) 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_list.js

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = (props) => {
    const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
        return <VideoListItem key={video.etag} video={video} />
    });

    return (
        <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
            {videoItems}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default VideoList;
```

video_detail.js

```
import React from 'react';

const VideoListItem = (props) => {
    return <ul>Video</ul>
};

export default VideoListItem;
```

Comment: Should ```<ul>Video</ul>``` be ```<li>Video</li>``` ?

Comment: file name is: `video_detail.js` but you are importing `import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';` is it correct??? i think it should be: `import VideoListItem from './video_detail';`

Answer (score 0):

This error :

```
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
```

usually happens because of your import statements. double check the import statements. as  Mayank Shukla  mentioned on comments, you import VideoListItem with a different file name in your import statement.

also you need to return `<li>Video</li>` in your VideoListItem component.